# How to read the exact date format from Excel cell having formula field with Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have Excel date format of the cell as:
MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM

I need to fetch the same format irrespective of any format given in excel using apache poi

Can someone help ?

Comment: What have you tried? Please try using `DataFormatter` as shown in first part of [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents). If that not fulfills your needs then please show used code in your question together with what the code produces and what you wants to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? Please try using DataFormatter as shown in first part of Getting the cell contents. If that not fulfills your needs then please show used code in your question together with what the code produces and what you wants to get.
@axel ritcher

This worked